# 3D rotation matrix (rotate to another reference system)

Tags: math, matrix, rotation

### Is there a direct approach to construct a rotation matrix from the following input?

Say there is a standard perpendicular reference: `X[1,0,0], Y[0,1,0], Z[0,0,1]` and I want rotation matrix to rotate it to match another perpendicular reference `X'[a1,b1,c1], Y'[a2,b2,c2], Z'[a3,b3,c3]`. Vectors are unit vectors.
Is it possible that the matrix would be like below?

```
a1, a2, a3
b1, b2, b3
c1, c2, c3
```

Comment: Yes, use the transpose of 3x3 matrix you have posted above to transform the points from the XYZ system to the X'Y'Z'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given points defined in a `XYZ` coordinate system, you transform them to a `X'Y'Z` coordinate system with a `3x3` rotation matrix. In general, the components of the local `a`, `b`, and `c` axes arranged in columns in the world coordinates represent the `local->world` transformation for that system such that

```
| x_world |   | a1 b1 c1 | | x_local |
| y_world | = | a2 b2 c2 | | y_local |
| z_world |   | a3 b3 c3 | | z_local |
```

and the reverse transformation (with a [matrix transpose](http://www.mathwords.com/t/transpose_of_a_matrix.htm))

```
| x_local |   | a1 a2 a3 | | x_world |
| y_local | = | b1 b2 b3 | | y_world |
| z_local |   | c1 c2 c3 | | z_world |
```

Now to transform between any two coordinate systems with `local->world` rotation matrices `XYZ` and `X'Y'Z'` (note in your case `XYZ` is the 3x3 identity matrix) you chain the above for

```
point_x'y'z' = transpose(X'Y'Z') * (XYZ) * point_xyz

| x' |    | a1 b1 c1 | | x |   | a1 x + b1 y + c1 z |
| y' | =  | a2 b2 c2 | | y | = | a2 x + b2 y + c2 z |
| z' |    | a3 b3 c3 | | z |   | a3 x + b3 y + c3 z |
```

Comment: your answer reminded me the exact maths we learned at linear algebra course! good explanation

Comment: Does this system also work for tensors? I am trying the same transformation on a strain tensor.

Comment: I think tensors follow **congruent** transformations where `σ_A = R*σ_Β*transpose(R)` with `σ` a 3×3 tensor, and `R` the rotation matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the transformation from identity to any other transform is the other transform. Usually you do not call these things rotation matrices because they represent any arbitrary transformation. It may be that the transformation may not be achievable by rotation alone, as the transformation may be mirrored about one or two planes.

Please note while your using column vector's it is perfectly possible to also use row vectors in which case your results are just transposed, and multiplication order the reverse. Mathematically its the same thing. So check your system